# How to change font style?

Tags: fonts, latex

I have two text in latex. I need to have the same font style. Please, help me to change the font size in example 1 to the one that is in example 2. (I include packages that I use)

**Example 1:**

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{plain}

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}


\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}



    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
\setheadsepline[122mm]{0.3mm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%
\doublespacing
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
  \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
```

asdsdsdsdsdsds s sd sd sd sd sd sd s s sd s  ds ds ds  dsd sd sd sd s dsd sds  sddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second block seems to use the default text font, so you simply remove the manual font settings from your first document to get the same font.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

%\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{plain}

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%%FONTS
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
%\setmainfont[
%SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
%BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
%ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
%]
%{Fontin.otf}
%%%

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```